# More Than One H1 Tag Error on Osclass Website

Tags: php, html, osclass

I have a website [MyMobPrice](https://mymobprice.com) and I am using OsClass for my website. On each product page I am getting this error - More than One H1 Tag found.

Here are two H1 codes for desktop and mobile.

For desktop:

```
<div class="basic isDesktop isTablet">
  <h1>
    <?php if(del_check_category_price(osc_item_category_id())) { ?>
      <div class="price mbCl3 p-<?php echo osc_item_price(); ?>x<?php if(osc_item_price() <= 0) { ?> isstring<?php } ?>"><?php echo osc_item_formated_price(); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>
  </h1>
          
  <?php if($make_offer_enabled) { ?>
    <a href="#" id="mk-offer" class="make-offer-link" data-item-id="<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>" data-item-currency="<?php echo osc_item_currency(); ?>" data-ajax-url="<?php echo mo_ajax_url(); ?>&moAjaxOffer=1&itemId=<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>"><?php _e('Submit your offer', 'delta'); ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

For mobile:

```
<div class="basic isMobile">
  <h1>
    <?php if(del_check_category_price(osc_item_category_id())) { ?>
      <div class="price mbCl3 p-<?php echo osc_item_price(); ?>x<?php if(osc_item_price() <= 0) { ?> isstring<?php } ?>"><?php echo osc_item_formated_price(); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>
  </h1>
          
  <?php if($make_offer_enabled) { ?>
    <a href="#" id="mk-offer" class="make-offer-link" data-item-id="<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>" data-item-currency="<?php echo osc_item_currency(); ?>" data-ajax-url="<?php echo mo_ajax_url(); ?>&moAjaxOffer=1&itemId=<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>"><?php _e('Submit your offer', 'delta'); ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

How can I show only one H1 tag?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I remove code for mobile, and edited code for desktop for all device. and now its showing only one H1 tag on product page. please check is this code ok.

```
<div class="basic">
      <h1>
        <?php if(del_check_category_price(osc_item_category_id())) { ?>
          <div class="price mbCl3 p-<?php echo osc_item_price(); ?>x<?php if(osc_item_price() <= 0) { ?> isstring<?php } ?>"><?php echo osc_item_formated_price(); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        
        <?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      
      
      
      <?php if($make_offer_enabled) { ?>
        <a href="#" id="mk-offer" class="make-offer-link" data-item-id="<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>" data-item-currency="<?php echo osc_item_currency(); ?>" data-ajax-url="<?php echo mo_ajax_url(); ?>&moAjaxOffer=1&itemId=<?php echo osc_item_id(); ?>"><?php _e('Submit your offer', 'delta'); ?></a>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
```